# Android Webview SwipeRefreshLayout doesn't allow to scroll down

Tags: android, webview, swiperefreshlayout

When I try to scroll down the page in my `WebView` scrolling triggers `SwipeRefreshLayout` instead of `WebView` itself. How can I limit the area to top of my Activity?

I tried to write something like this but couldn't get done

```
mySwipeRefreshLayout.onTouchEvent(new MotionEvent() {
            public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
            final int action = event.getAction();
            switch (action) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                    final MotionEvent eventCopy = MotionEvent.obtain(event);
                    final float eventY = eventCopy.getY();

                    // Handle only top %20
                    if (eventY < (Percentage / 5)) {
                        int mCurrPercentage = 20;
                        // ......
                    } else {
                        // ......
                    }
                }
                break; 
            });
        }
```

Comment: You cold go with a solution by extending SwypeRefreshLayout and override onTouchEvent such it cancels the refresh if the DOWN touch is below some threshould

Comment: @MarcosVasconcelos how can I specify the threshold? And is there any sample code?

Comment: No samples, the threshold should be a percent of the size of the view height that fit your requirement of being on top.

Comment: @MarcosVasconcelos I edited my post I have written some code but I get errors. Can you help me to implement this? Thank you for your kindness.

Comment: Kind this, but you have to extends SwypeRefreshLayout and override onTouchEvent instead (you are just sending one event this way you posted) so uyou have access to super.onTouchEvent if you want the view to handle or cancel the touch if is over the threshould